# Making a singleton have all static fields

Tags: java, android, singleton

I always wondered, since a singleton allows use to have just have one reference to an object, which we get by using the static method getInstance, why can’t we decide to make all fields in a singleton static?

Comment: we can, but what would be the benefit?

Comment: @stultuske it’s memory inefficient yeah?, since those static fields can’t be garbage collected, meaning once we are done using our singleton, those fields still remain taking up space, so it’s better to make them instance variables right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Static members are part of class and thus remain in memory till
>   application terminates and can’t be ever garbage collected. Using
>   excess of static members sometime predicts that you fail to design
>   your product and trying to cop of with static / procedural
>   programming. It denotes that object oriented design is compromised.
>   This can result in memory over flow. Also there are certain
>   disadvantages if you make any method static in Java for example you
>   can not override any static method in Java so it makes testing harder
>   you can not replace that method with mock. Since static method
>   maintains global state they can create subtle bug in concurrent
>   environment which is hard to detect and fix.

So by making every method static we eliminate the purpose of making singleton class which is to **Saves memory**

Comment: Ohh that makes sense, so if every member is static, it’s basically a waste of memory, and since it can never be garbage collected assuming we are done with the single ton, so it’s better to make those members instance

Comment: so instead of making them static fields that don’t get garbage collected, we make them instance fields so that once we are done using them , they can be garbage collected instead of taking up memory

Comment: you can accept the answer so that it'll helpful to other.

Comment: Singletons are almost always used for purposes other than just saving memory.

Comment: yes i know I've answered as per the context of question